# there.are.illegal.characters.for.barcode.128 exception when using CODE128_UCC in itextsharp 5.5.4 .net

Tags: itext, gs1-128

When attempting to create an GS1-128 barcode I encounter the following exception: there.are.illegal.characters.for.barcode.128.in.1

```
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode barcode = null;
        barcode = new Barcode128();
        barcode.CodeType = iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CODE128_UCC;
        barcode.GenerateChecksum = true;
        barcode.Code = code;
        using (var image = barcode.CreateDrawingImage(Color.Black, Color.White))
```

Answer (score 1):

After pulling down the source it looks like there might be a bug in the library the code calling into GetRawText. It will pass CodeSet Auto which fails the assertions in in the method. I determined the following to be an acceptable workaround:

```
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode barcode = null;
        barcode = new Barcode128();
        barcode.CodeType = iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CODE128_RAW;
        barcode.GenerateChecksum = true;
        barcode.Code = Barcode128.GetRawText(code, true, Barcode128.Barcode128CodeSet.C);
        using (var image = barcode.CreateDrawingImage(Color.Black, Color.White))
```

Answer (score 0):

code.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)

Worked for me. try this.